# Rails ignore coder in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I need to run a rake task to migrate data in my model

```rb
class Translation < ApplicationRecord
  store :body, accessors: [:object_body], coder: YAML
  belongs_to :team
end
```

and need to access `body` as text.
I don't want to remove the coder part since a lot of logic relies on that.
Can I access `body` without decoding to a ruby object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new method on the model.

```rb
class Translation < ApplicationRecord
  store :body, accessors: [:object_body], coder: YAML
  belongs_to :team

  def raw_body
    read_attribute_before_type_cast('body')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`read_attribute_before_type_cast`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html) should work. It will return the value before typecasting or deserialization.

```
raw_body = obj.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:body)
```